# Как организовать иерархию классов для приложения?

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать приложение, где нужно покормить кота.

Нужно, что бы кота можно было покормить, поиграть с ним, и вылечить. Так же что бы возраст влиял на то сколько прибавится или уменьшится к уровню кота здоровья, лечения и сытость и этот этап нужно сделать с помощью паттерна стратегии.

> Вопрос: Как Организовать Иерархию Классов для такого приложения?

Темы все вроде знаю, а вот соединить всё никак не получается!

Я сделал базовый класс в котором определил два свойства (name, age) и три поля (ур. Сытости, ур. Настроения ур. Здоровья) в конструкторе класса, который принимает два параметра имя и возраст. Проинициализировал их и оставшиеся переменные. Создал метод (printcat) который выводит информацию о коте.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestCats.Hangry;
using TestCats.Health;
using TestCats.Mood;

namespace TestCats.CatsFolder
{

    public class BaseCats
    {
        protected string _name { get; set; }
        protected int _age { get; set; }
        protected int _Hangry { get; set; }
        protected int _Mood { get; set; }
        protected int _Health { get; set; }

        //public IHangry _hangry;
        //public IHealth _health;
        //public IMood _mood;

        public BaseCats()
        {

        }


        public BaseCats(string name, int age)
        {
            _name = name;
            _age = age;
            _Hangry = 0;
            _Mood = 0;
            _Health = 0;

            //_hangry = new HangryNo();
            //_mood = new MoodNo();
            //_health = new HealthNo();
        }

        public void HangryMethod()
        {
            PrintCat();
        }
        public void MoodMethod()
        {
            PrintCat();
        }
        public void HealthMethod()
        {
            PrintCat();
        }

        public void MethodGet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Имя кота - {_name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Возраст кота - {_age}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Уровень настроения - {_Hangry}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Уровень настроения - {_Mood}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Уровень здоровья - {_Health}");
        }
        public virtual void PrintCat() { }
    }
}
```

В файле  Program.cs создал лист в который добавляю котов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestCats.CatsFolder;

namespace TestCats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите кота или создайте нового\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Для выбора кота нажмите цыфру соответствующую коту (1,2,3 и т.д.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Что бы создать кота введите (C)\n\n");
            Print();

            List<BaseCats> baseCats = new List<BaseCats>();
            BaseCats baseCatsAdd = new BaseCats();

            while (true)
            {
                Print();
                Console.WriteLine($"1 - Ману");
                Console.WriteLine($"2 - Марго");
                Console.WriteLine("c - Create cats");
                Print();

                string EnterName = Console.ReadLine();


                switch (EnterName)
                {
                    case "1":
                        baseCats.Add(new CreateCat("Ману", 5));
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        baseCats.Add(new CreateCat("Марго", 7));
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя кота: ");
                            string name = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (name != string.Empty)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Введите возраст кота: ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Вы не чего не ввели. Попробуйте ещё раз.\n");
                                break;
                            }
                            int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            baseCats.Add(new CreateCat(name, age));
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Возникла ошибка. Попробуйте снова.\n");
                            break;
                        }
                }

                foreach (var cats in baseCats)
                {
                    cats.MethodGet();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }

        }

        public static void Print()
        {
            Console.Write("-------------------------------------------------\n");
        }

    }
}
```

А, как прибавлять здоровье , настроение и т.д. не могу понять.  Также есть класс кота в котором реализуется логика покорми кота с помощью switch,

```
using System;
using TestCats.Hangry;

namespace TestCats.CatsFolder
{
    class CreateCat: BaseCats
    {
        public CreateCat(string name, int age) : base(name, age)
        {
            PrintCat();
        }

        public override void PrintCat()
        {
            MethodHangry();
        }


        public void MethodHangry()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите покармит {_name} (1)");
            Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите поиграть с {_name} (2)");
            Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите вылечить {_name} (3)");
            Console.WriteLine($"Если вы не хотите кормить, играть и лечить кота {_name} то нажмите (n)");


            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            string Enter = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

            switch (Enter)
            {
                case "1":
                    if (_age < 6) { _Hangry += 10; }
                    if (_age > 5 || _age > 11) { _Hangry += 5; }
                    if (_age > 10) { _Hangry += 2; }
                    MethodGet();
                    break;

                case "2":
                    if (_age < 6) { _Mood += 10; }
                    if (_age > 5 || _age > 11) { _Mood += 5; }
                    if (_age > 10) { _Mood += 2; }
                    MethodGet();
                    break;

                case "3":
                    if (_age < 6) { _Health += 10; }
                    if (_age > 5 || _age > 11) { _Health += 5; }
                    if (_age > 10) { _Health += 2; }
                    MethodGet();
                    break;

                case "n":
                    if (_age < 6) { _Health -= 2; }
                    if (_age > 5 || _age > 11) { _Health -= 5; }
                    if (_age > 10) { _Health -= 10; }
                    MethodGet();
                    break;

                default:
                    MethodGet();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Создал класс (CreateCat) через который и создаю каждого кота.Теперь работает но не сохраняет значение. То одно работает, а другое нет, то наоборот.

Comment: А смысл в наследовании от BaseCats? Создаете котов используя класс BaseCats (тогда лучше его просто Cat назвать)

Comment: @gil9red Так как всех котов создаю с помощью этого класса. вот и назвал BaseCats

Comment: Я про `baseCats.Add(new ManuCat("Ману", 5));` и `baseCats.Add(new MargoCat("Марго", 7));`. В чем будет отличие ManuCat от MargoCat?

Comment: @gil9red Отличие только в имени и возрасте. То есть это два кота как бы. Функционал у них одинаковый.

Comment: Вот я к этому и веду. Ладно были бы у них какие-то особенности, например у Марго две головы, вторая говорит не мяв, а гав и если не кормить вторую голову, кусает первую, после чего требуется ее лечить :) Имя и возраст и так задается в базовом классе, поэтому можно работать только с одним классом.

Comment: @gil9red Интересная фантазия про головы! Весёлая игра бы была!!! Вы Имеете ввиду класс ManuCats не нужен?

Comment: Старался ) Да, нет смысла создавать новые сущности, если базовая покрывает всю нужду. Посмотрел BaseCats.PrintCat и мне кажется что он может стать общим для всех котов. Тоже касается и MethodHangry -- всех котов нужно будет кормить, а не только наследованных от базового класса, и наверняка способ кормежки (и место) для всех котов одинаковый

Comment: @gil9red Так я вроде просто создаю одного кота передав ему имя и возраст. Используя BaeCats. А, как нужно ? Метод PrintCat и MethodHangry общие я так и предполагал и думал они итак общие. И да кормёжка и т.д. это (хочешь покормить кота (да/нет) если да то к Hangry должно прибавиться 10 если коту от нуля до 5 если нет то отниматься 2 , к примеру. Ну и есть три возрастные категории.) А, вот как реализовать не могу понять. Сейчас код обновлю немного изменил но всё равно не работает. Мин через 30.

Comment: Вы не кота создаете, а тип кота. Например, типы могли быть такие: "домашняя кошка", "тигр", "лев" и это было бы оправдано, если у них уникальные особенности. А создавать кота можно и базовым классом: `baseCats.Add(new BaseCats("Ману", 5));`

Comment: @gil9red А, понял! Я это сделал по тому что думал воспользоваться поттерном стратегия. Изначально думал так сделать но не получилось ,а всё работало вот и не исправил. Вы правы!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80364/discussion-between-j-atisto-and-gil9red).

Comment: @gil9red Вроде так работает но  не сохраняет значение. То есть, при втором проходе цикла while значение, что к примеру покормил кота не сохраняться.

Comment: Так у вас на каждой итерации создается новый кот, даже если выбирать 1 или 2 -- появится новый кот. Если у вас есть предосозданные коты, то и добавляйте их в список до `while (true)`. Разделите логику. Например, сначала выбираете кота, сохраняете его объект и после работаете с объектом (конкретным котом), это можно через второй цикл `while (true)`

Comment: @gil9red А, как сохранить объект. Всегда с этим путаюсь.Имеется ввиду в List<> как я сделал только до while или по другому. Этого то я и не могу понять как сохранять объекты. Вот сказали что при каждой итерации новый кот, теперь понимаю сам не заметил. А, вот как схоронить не понимаю.

Comment: Да, можно в списке хранить. Или в словаре

Comment: @gil9red Если создать кота до цикла `baseCats.Add(new CreateCats("Ману", 5));` и добавить его. то как его выбрать при выборе 1?

Comment: @gil9red Если сможешь подскажи. Ну а, пока буду думать!

Comment: @gil9red Немного переформулировал вопрос! При создании до цыкала и вывода, что нужно вписать в case "1": тогда для выбора из созданных котов? Вместо (`baseCats.Add(new CreateCats("Ману", 5));`)

Comment: Проверяйте EnterName -- если там "c", то создаете нового кота, иначе это выбор кота по индексу, а значит приводите к числу и это число используйте для доступа к объекту в списке через индексацию. Ну и не забудьте что индексация начинается с 0, а не 1

Comment: @gil9red Буду пробовать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вопрос был про построение иерархии, то отвечу довольно абстрактно.
Вам нужен абстрактный (abstract) класс `CatBase`, который будет содержать:
1. свойства `Name`, `Age`, `Health`, `Mood`, `Hunger`, публичные (*public*) по чтению и защищённые (*protected*) для записи, а также метод `Print`. Теперь есть два путии:
1. Создать для каждого действия (кормить, играть, лечить) отдельный интерфейс, содержащий нужный метод и наследовать от них класс `CatBase`, предоставив их реализацию. (я считаю, что для вашего примера это будет излишеством :D)
2. Реализовать для каждого действия виртуальный (*virtual*) метод.

---

Вот так вот вы создали общее представление своего котейки. Чтобы добавить какой-то вид кота, вам необходимо создать соответствующий класс, наследовав его от `CatBase`. Если этот кот не будет содержать ничего уникального (зачем он тогда вообще нужен XD), то в нём даже ничего не нужно писать, просто создать и всё. и тогда работа с множеством котов будет выглядеть примерно так

```
//Предположим, что мы создали пустые классы SimpleCat, OrangeCat, GreenCat
//И все они наследуются от CatBase
var cats=new List<CatBase>(){
            new Simplecat("teen", 14), 
            new OrangeCat("orange", 88),
            new GreenCat("grenny", 1)};
cats[0].Print();
cats[0].Feed();
cats[0].Print();
```

Очевидно, что я показал только сам принцип создания и как с ними работать (просто у вас возник такой вопрос к другому отвечающему), а написать интерфейс для работы с котами не составит труда.

---

UPD. пример реализации интерфейса.

```
interface ICanEat{
    bool Feed();
}
class CatBase: ICanEat{
    public bool Feed(){
        //Тут уже сами подставите свою логику
        if (Age%2==0)
            Hunger+=10; 
        else
            Hunger+=5;
        //Вот это чушь для примера использования :D
    }
//Тут по такому же принципу всё остальное
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Примерно так я и сделал в самый первый раз. И всё работало на уровне меню и выбора. Но не работала логика. Сейчас здесь многие написали варианты и везде я нашёл как можно сделать мою задачу! Просто немного путаюсь в иерархиях. И Из за этого не могу доделать как нужно.

Comment: Про кота (SimpleCat, OrangeCat, GreenCat) при таком раскладе я знаю как сделать с помощью паттерна стратегии. Но мне в таком контексте он не подходит. по этому и отказался от похожего варианта как вы описали. Через него мне нужно сделать что бы (кот кормился и значение Health, Mood, Hunger менялось через интерфейс). Где я и застрял. Сейчас сделал то что нужно, но без интерфейса.

Comment: @j.Atisto, Но я описал и вариант с интерфейсами, в чём именно проблема?

Comment: Я не могу понять как именно реализовать интерфейс. Не в смысле как он пишется и используется, а где его и как правильно применить. То есть можно написать интерфейс IMount к примеру как писали в ответе. В нём метод Food(); ,а вот где именно его реализовать и как настроить взаимодействие с базовым классом не пойму. И если бы там просто выводил на консоль кот поел и всё. Тут всё понятно. А, как сделать реализацию что бы значения в базовом классе (Health, Mood, Hunger ) менялись и сохранялись не могу понять.

Comment: При создании интерфейса (protecter IMount _mount; ) в конструкторе (_mount = new ???) вот тут и что делать я и не знаю!

Comment: При варианте с цветными котами (new OrangCat) и всё понятно , а здесь мне нужно ещё что бы при этом изменялись значения (Hangry, Health, Mood)

Comment: @j.Atisto, добавил в ответ

Comment: Ну вроде понял спасибо! Сейчас попробую!

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос: Как Организовать Иерархию Классов для такого приложения?

Ответ: коты должны реализовывать интерфейс IMouth, кормите котов методом Feed.
У Вас должно быть минимум 3 файла с (по возможности) одним классом внутри: main, cat и menu (или UI, как хотите)

в Main у вас код программы, очевидно.
в Menu у вас отрисовка интерфейса, обработка нажатий и навигация по системе.

Пользователь, нажимая клавиши, переходит по меню и кормит котов через интерфейс взаимодействия с системой, а система кормит виртуальных котов от имени пользователя через IMouth(рот) вызовом Feed.
Класс BaseCats реализует логику изменения настроения и хп в зависимости от Feed и времени, когда Feed был выполнен.

Не сочтите за упорку, но имхо это примерно так и должно делаться в ооп: вы представляете все объекты в виде классов. Классы взаимодействуют между собой интерфейсами.

Comment: Я понимаю что так и должно быть в ООП. Но я новичок в практике ООП. Не могли бы поподробней объяснить! У меня тоже 3 класса (файла) BaseCat, ManuCat(хотя его я убрал и использую базовый класс) и Program. Мне нужно создать интерфейс по мимо этих классов. В интерфейсе будет метод Feed() , как правильно его использовать если я котов создаю к примеру через базовый класс `baseCats.Add(new BaseCats("Ману", 5));` таким образом мне нужно создать ещё класс и в нём реализовать интерфейс. Или создавать нужно по другому? В этом я и путаюсь постоянно! Не могли бы объяснить  по подробней?

Comment: как к через интерфейс добавить HP коту? Если реализовать в классе Menu то он должен наследоваться от Базового класса?

Comment: для кормления кота вы должны выбрать его через Menu приложения с клавиатуры и нажать "покорпить". на вход вы даёте ему еду `Feed(int calories)`. в теле функции кот уже сам рассчитает, сколько хп ему прибавить, и на сколько поднимется его настроение, в зависимости от внутренних свойств кота

Comment: базовый класс baseCat долен служить для описания полей и методов, присущих всем котам. а от него должны наследоваться коты другой породы. хотите создать кота? сделайте это через new BaseCat(). либо добавляйте их в Pitimnik.Add(new BaseCat()). baseCats.Add( - лишнее, вы и так создаёте объект кота через new

Comment: исходите из описания объектов в реальном мире. придумайте, где вы будете хранить котов. список котов - простое, но неправильное решение, ведь когда вы ищете кота дома, вы подходите к нему и берёте его сразу (или по имени, знаете, в какой клетке он сидит). при поиске кота по списку вы будете брать каждого кота и смотреть, ваш ли он. лучше раскидать их в hashmap или dictionary.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я сделал через интерфейс как было написано выше.

Answer (score 1):

Интереса ради переписал код этой консольной игрушки, сделав его рабочим:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Cat
{
    protected string _Name { get; set; }
    protected int _Age { get; set; }
    protected int _Hangry { get; set; }
    protected int _Mood { get; set; }
    protected int _Health { get; set; }

    public Cat(string name, int age)
    {
        _Name = name;
        _Age = age;

        _Hangry = 0;
        _Mood = 0;
        _Health = 0;
    }

    public bool SelectAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите покормить {_Name} (1)");
        Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите поиграть с {_Name} (2)");
        Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотите вылечить {_Name} (3)");
        Console.WriteLine($"Если вы не хотите кормить, играть и лечить кота {_Name} то нажмите (n)");
        Console.WriteLine($"Если вы закончили играться с {_Name} нажмите (q)");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

        string enter = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");

        bool ok = false;

        switch (enter)
        {
            case "1":
                if (_Age < 6) { _Hangry += 10; }
                if (_Age > 5 || _Age > 11) { _Hangry += 5; }
                if (_Age > 10) { _Hangry += 2; }
                ok = true;
                break;

            case "2":
                if (_Age < 6) { _Mood += 10; }
                if (_Age > 5 || _Age > 11) { _Mood += 5; }
                if (_Age > 10) { _Mood += 2; }
                ok = true;
                break;

            case "3":
                if (_Age < 6) { _Health += 10; }
                if (_Age > 5 || _Age > 11) { _Health += 5; }
                if (_Age > 10) { _Health += 2; }
                ok = true;
                break;

            case "n":
                if (_Age < 6) { _Health -= 2; }
                if (_Age > 5 || _Age > 11) { _Health -= 5; }
                if (_Age > 10) { _Health -= 10; }
                ok = true;
                break;

            case "q":
                ok = false;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        PrintInfo();

        return ok;
    }

    public void PrintInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Имя кота - {_Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Возраст кота - {_Age}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Уровень настроения - {_Hangry}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Уровень настроения - {_Mood}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Уровень здоровья - {_Health}");
    }
}


namespace csharp__foo_bar
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Print()
        {
            Console.Write("-------------------------------------------------\n");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите кота или создайте нового\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Для выбора кота нажмите цифру соответствующую коту (1,2,3 и т.д.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Что бы создать кота введите (+)\n\n");
            Print();

            // Коты по умолчанию
            List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
            {
                new Cat("Ману", 5),
                new Cat("Марго", 5)
            };
            Cat currentCat = null;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Print();
                    Console.WriteLine($"1 - Ману");
                    Console.WriteLine($"2 - Марго");
                    Console.WriteLine("+ - Создать кота");
                    Print();

                    string value = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (value == "+")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите имя кота: ");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Введите возраст кота: ");
                        int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        currentCat = new Cat(name, age);
                        cats.Add(currentCat);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int number = Int32.Parse(value);
                        currentCat = cats[number - 1];
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Возникла ошибка: '{e}'. Попробуйте снова.\n");
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Текущий выбранный кот:");
                currentCat.PrintInfo();

                // Синтаксически упрощенный while, который будет выполняться пока SelectAction возвращает true
                while (currentCat.SelectAction());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**PS.** ради наглядности убрал пару проверок

Comment: Спасибо! про bool это очень хорошее решение. Забыл совсем!